# My code to find all pairs of numbers such that x^y > y^x producing the wrong output

Tags: c++, exponent, error-correction

The problem is: given two arrays of positive integers of lengths `m` and `n` find all pairs of `(x, y)` such that  `x^y > y^x`. (Raising the left operand to the power of the right)

I have followed the following logic:

1. if `x = 1` then no ordered pairs satisfies the conditions.
2. if `y = 1` and `x != 1`, the condition is satisfied for all `x`.
3. the condition is true for all remaining cases where `y > x`.
4. Exceptions are : `(2, 3), (2, 4) and (3, 2)`

My code is:

```
    int main(){
        int n, m;
        cin >> m >> n;
        int a[m], b[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) cin >> a[i];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> b[i];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
            if(a[i] != 1){  
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    if(b[j] == 1) count++;
                    else if(a[i] == 2 && b[j] >= 5) count++;
                    else if(a[i] == 3 &&(b[j] == 2 || b[j] >=4)) count++;
                    else if(b[j] > a[i]) count++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }
```

For certain large outputs (on geeksforgeeks) the code outputs a value of one more than the correct answer. (e.g., 12575 instead of the expected output of 12574, an error of 1)

I am unable to figure out where the code fails. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `a[n]` and `b[m];`  are ill-formed expressions, variable length arrays are not legal in C++. You should use `std::vector`.

Comment: @anastaciu they're GCC/clang compiler extensions. Technically it will still work, but it's bad practice to rely on compiler extensions when portable code could be used. `std::vector` is an excellent recommendation, or `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` since the array doesn't need to be resized.

Comment: @anastaciu Thanks for the tip! However, the code still produces the incorrect output, even with vectors.

Comment: By `x^y > y^x` you mean raising `x` to the power of `y` and vice versa? Because as c code you're just doing a bitwise-xor, which is a symmetric operation.

Comment: @J.Schultke, correct. Not only it's not portable but it also invalidates the use of some STL functions, for instance, `std::size` works with fixed size arrays but not with VLAs.

Comment: @BennyK Sorry for the ambiguity, the operation is raising to the power

Comment: @KaushikMahadevan, yes, the comment is not a fix for your problem, it's a mear advice on coding practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're counting both `(2, 4)` and `(2, 3)`, since those cases end up in the last condition.

The simplest way to treat them as exceptions is to make sure that you handle all "2 cases" at once:

```
if (a[i] == 2) 
    if (b[j] >= 5) 
         count++;
```

or

```
if (a[i] == 2) 
    count += b[j] >= 5;
```

When your code is supposed to make exceptions for certain cases, make sure that you test those exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong sizes for your arrays:

```
    int a[n], b[m];                          // a[n], b[m]
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) cin >> a[i];  // a[m]
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> b[i];  // b[n]
```

This means that if the arrays are of different sizes, you'll have undefined behavior.

You are probably also reading in the array sizes in the incorrect order:

```
cin >> m >> n;
```

Suggested changes to make it easier to find the problem using standard C++17 (no VLA:s):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    if(size_t n, m; std::cin >> n >> m) {
        std::vector<unsigned> a(n);
        std::vector<unsigned> b(m);

        for(auto& v : a) std::cin >> v;
        for(auto& v : b) std::cin >> v;

        int count = 0;
        for(auto aval : a) {
            if(aval != 1) {
                for(auto bval : b) {
                    if(bval == 1)
                        count++;
                    else if(aval == 2 && bval >= 5)
                        count++;
                    else if(aval == 3 && (bval == 2 || bval >= 4))
                        count++;
                    else if(bval > aval)
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << count << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I changed the declarations but the output is still not correct.

Comment: @KaushikMahadevan I  think you read the array sizes in the wrong order too. See my edit. Edit: Ok, you corrected that part now I see.

Comment: I tried implementing your code, but didn't get the required output. It still gives me the same incorrect output. I think the problem lies with the logic of the solution rather than its actual implementation. Thanks for the input though, I learned quite a bit from your code snippet.

Comment: @KaushikMahadevan You're welcome! Yes, I didn't change the logic. I just wanted to make sure it didn't have any mistakes causing UB and make it easier to fix the logic. :)